# get row id/key of each row in database using python google appengine

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

I need to get the row id of each row so that I can use it as primary key.
This is what I'm doing

```
    qr = MoreGames.query()
    res = qr.fetch()
    if res:
        data = []
        for row in res:
            d = {'id':row.key().id(),'title':row.title,'description':row.description,'link':row.link}
            data.append(d);
```

Whenever I use row.key().id() it gives me '500 internal server error'.

Comment: have you tried printing row? or dir(row)?

Comment: `db` or `ndb`? you need to include the full traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `.query()` suggests you're using NDB rather than DB, in which case '`key`' is a property rather than a method, so:

```
row.key.id()
```

to get the id-part of the key.

Comment: res = DB.get_by_id(game_id) how to get data back using this id?

Comment: I got this error:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'id'

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging.

Most likely your key has a name instead of an id.  Try id_or_name() instead of id().